# Partial Query of a django JSONField

Tags: python, django

I have a model with a django JSONField. The JSONField has a key called 'name'. I want to search across my model, for users whose names contain Foo; something like :

```
User.objects.filter(jsonfield['name']__icontains='foo')
```

As far as I have researched there is no easy way to do this. My next alternative is to add a new column for jsonfield['name'] so I can search it. Although the fix I am looking for needs to be quick, I am also open to know my more involved options so I can refactor later. Thank you.

Comment: What JSONField are you using? Are you using PostgreSQL?

Comment: I am using [this](https://github.com/bradjasper/django-jsonfield) jsonfield and yes I am on postgerSQL

Comment: You might consider upgrading to the Django 1.9 beta, which has native support for Postgres JSON fields including querying: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield

Comment: Thank you. I will consider it. I think probably i will wait until its out of beta.